# Transition Diagram of a Universal Turing Machine

Tags: reference-request, computability, turing-machines, universal-computation

I have searched the web for the transition diagram of a universal Turing machine without luck. Is anyone aware of such a diagram?

I need this as a reference, so preferably a book or a published article. I don't want anything strange, just a standard Turing Machine with one tape that computes the Universal Turing Machine. The tape will contain a Turing machine and an input string. The rest of the tape is filled with blank.

I would prefer historic references.

Comment: Maybe this Wolfram demonstration is close to what you are looking for: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RuleCaseTransitionDiagramsForTheWolfram23TuringMachine/ . I think a similar style was used in Wolfram's book 'A new kind of science'.

Comment: According to the information found on this web page (http://www.rdrop.com/~half/General/UTM/index.html), the complete description of an UTM is contained in one of the first editions of the book: "*Formal Languages and Their Relation to Automata*" by Hopcroft & Ullman. Perhaps someone can search the book in its library and see if the information is correct (... and scan the pages with the UTM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the book:

```
@book{Hopcroft:1969:FLR:1096945,
 author = {Hopcroft, John E. and Ullman, Jeffrey D.},
 title = {Formal languages and their relation to automata},
 year = {1969},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley Longman Publishing Co., Inc.},
 address = {Boston, MA, USA},
}
```

and [this is a link to a pdf scan of the UM description (7 pages)](http://www.fractalmuse.org/misc/FLTRA_HU_UM.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some references:

- Claude Shannon, "A universal Turing machine with two internal states", 1956.
- Marvin Minsky, "A 6-symbol 6-state Universal Turing Machine", 1960.
- Shigeru Watanabe, "[5-Symbol 8-State and 5-Symbol 6-State Universal Turing Machines](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/321088.321090)", 1961.

Also Odifreddi writes ["Classical Recursion Theory", vol I, p. 133]:

> "..., and explicit constructions of universal Turing machines are in Turing
>   [[1936]](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/reprint/s2-42/1/230), Wang [[1957a]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.19570030602) and in many textbooks, e.g. Hermes [1965], Minsky
>   [1967], Arbib [1969], Hopcroft and Ullman [1979]. More information on
>   the topic is in Davis [1956], [1957], Shannon [1956], Rogers [1967]
>   and Priese [1979]."